# How to remove offers4u(Adware) completely from Google chrome on windows 8.1?

Tags: google-chrome, ads, malware-detection, trojan

When I visit the websites,this adware is showing too many ads, & it covers all the webpage.I tried to uninstall it, and block it by chrome extensions but it doesn't work. I tried different software to remove it, even I uninstalled chrome and installs a new chrome still it is showing bulk of ads. What should I do? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this will be applicable, as I had to fight different "brand" of adware, but I suppose it's usually all the same around.

First of all I highly recommend doing a complete scan with [Malwarebytes Antimalware](https://www.malwarebytes.org/antimalware/), as it mostly does recognize adware as malware.

If that is not enough, searching the filesystem and also windows registry and removing any files and keys connected to it usually works. You may have to do that in safe mode, if the adware runs some service or process on the background. That said, do look at the running services aswell.

*The rest applies only if the adware changes your homepage, which a quick google search says it doesn't:*

(Be of course careful to not remove parts of your browser or system - even the registry contain homepage settings, in that case, rewrite it to a homepage of your choice, instead of completely removing it.)

Also, when reinstalling chrome, did you remove all your configurations etc. as well? Check for homepage and default search engine configurations as well as all the chrome links (icons on your desktop and start menu etc.), which can have a homepage written after the application location.

The key is to find the right keyword to search for - I think in my case it was the "company" that produced the adware, whose name I probably found in the name of the homepage the adware set. But I'm not sure I remember that right.

Please do inquire if you need some more clarification.

Comment: Then mark your question as answered, if you don't need anything more :)

Answer (score 0):

it is because your pc has any backdoor services installed so just **identify unknown services and delete them** and this malware set chrome default search engine with any **unknown search engine so delete this search engine from chrome and change your desire search engine** for that purpose follow this tutorial 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZuM1tjncumE 

which has step by step guide to Manually remove any google chrome malware virus related to search engine without using any software.
search engine default redirect virus examples are
safefinder.com
safesearch.ch
Hoho Search virus
mystartsearch.com
web search 
feed sonic search 
etc